# how can I config css style about fixing height?

Tags: css, header, height, css-position

I have some problem about css layout.

I wrote the code like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<style>
html { height:100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 68.75%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}  
#header {
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  height: 100px;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 370px;
  background: #ffdab9;
  height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  background: #eee8aa;
  width: 370px;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

then, the thing what I want to do is

1. "header"'s height is 100 pixel.
2. "sidebar(left side)"'s width id 370 pixel.
3. "content(right side)"'s width is relative.
4. When I control the browser smaller, I do not want browser to make "scroll bar".
   like http://maps.google.com. google maps never make scroll bar when any resizing browser.

num.4 is most important that I told.

If the goal is made it, my code can be fixed all. Please give me any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two css changes (also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQqe4/)):

add `overflow: hidden` to `body`

```
body {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

change `position` to `relative` in `#header`:

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

=== UPDATE ===

There are (at least) three possible solutions, but none is perfect:

1.) Your example site from google calculates the (content) height at the beginning and after each resize with javascript.
Negative: not css only, you need a script.

2.) Add the height of the header (here 100px) to the css bottom definition of all elements in the sidebar and content (see [demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/xQqe4/3/)).
Negative: if the header height changes, you have to update all bottom definitions too.

```
#words { 
    bottom: 102px; 
    ...
}
```

3.) Use the css function [calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) for the `#wrapper` to calculate the real height (see [demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/xQqe4/4/)).
Negative: at the moment it works [only with firefox4 (and above) and IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

```
#wrapper {
    ...
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: It works. But I think "overflow: hidden" is clipping the part below. I try to put some words included content(right side) like: #words {
 position: absolute; 
 right: 123px; 
 bottom: 2px; 
 color: black; 
 font-family: Arial,sans-serif; 
 font-size: 11px; 
 white-space: nowrap; 
 text-align: right;
} The words is not appeared..

Comment: And html is <div id="content"><div id="words"><span>INEGI</span></div></div>